# Updating a record from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table A with values:

TABLE A:

```
  Data1 Data2 Data3 
 --------------------
   Val2  null  val3
   null  ValB  Val3
```

and Table B:

```
Data1   Data2    
---------------
Value1  Value2
```

Now I want to update the 2nd Row of Table1 with the value1 of TableB by for Val3 by checking the value in TableB wherein the Val2 of tableA is equal to Value1 of TableB.

I had tried to update it using a subQuery like

```
update TableA 
set Data1=
    (Select distinct(B.Data1)
    from TableB B,TableA A
    where A.Data1=B.Data2 and B.Data2 is null)
where Data3=Val3
```

the query is executing successfully but the record is not getting updated. 
the tableA is having specific records for the set 
i.e. it can be 
`<Data2,Data3> or <null,Data3>` (Data3 cannot be null)

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

TIA,

Regards,

Abhishek

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is **not** a function. Writing `DISTINCT(col)` is identical to `DISTINCT col`. It only works because it's legal to put a column name between brackets.

Comment: `where A.Data1=B.Data2 and B.Data2 is null` -- please check this.  This where clause cannot return true.

Comment: Fix your example tables so we can understand what you are saying. You say “the Val2 of tableA is equal to Value1 of TableB”, but the condition is `A.Data1=B.Data2` (no value1 in column Data2). Make the question clear and unambiguous, and you'll be half way to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your query works, it just is not matching like you want it to.

Based on your question (not your sample data, which doesn't seem to work to your requirements) I put this together to hopefully point you on the correct direction

```
create table tablea(data1 varchar2(8) , data2 varchar2(8), data3 varchar2(8) );
create table tableb(data1 varchar2(8) , data2 varchar2(8) );

insert into tablea values('Val2',null,'Val3');
insert into tablea values(null,'ValB','Val3');

insert into tableB values('Value1','ValB');
insert into tableB values('NewValue','Val2');

update TableA 
  set Data1 = nvl((Select B.Data1
                 from TableB B  --no need for join, I believe you want to join to the 'updating table'
                where /*TableA.Data1=B.Data2 
                     and B.Data2 is null*/ -- this won't work, null DOES NOT EQUAL NULL
                     TableA.Data1=B.Data2 
                ) ,TableA.Data1)  --this way, if no data is returned from tableB.data1 to tableA join we will retain tableA.Data1 value
where Data3='Val3' ;


select *  from tableA;


DATA1    DATA2    DATA3    
-------- -------- -------- 
NewValue          Val3     
         ValB     Val3
```

please look at the initial questions in regards to your questions, your WHERE clause (and joining) is making it so things don't work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very general outline of how to update a table based on a join between itself and another table:

```
UPDATE TableA
 set
   TableAColumn = tb.TableBColumn
  ,TableAOtherColumn = tb.TableBOtherColumn
  ,etc.
 from TableA ta
  inner join TableB tb
   on tb.JoinColumn = ta.JoinColumn
 where ta.FurtherCriteriaColumn = @DesiredTargetValue
  and/or tb.OtherCrieterioColumn < = > @SomeOtherValue
  etc.
```

There are a few different ways this can be done, this is just the basic template I use.

Comment: I may be mis-reading this, but this syntax does not work in oracle. (update t1 set val = tb.val{ from ....}).  You may do a update ts set (colA,colB) = (select col1,col2 from ...)

Comment: It is indeed true. But let's not revert the subject: Why post not working syntax?