# How do I update a table with fields selected from another table?

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sequel

Although there are many questions similar to this, such as 
"[Updating a record from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819882/updating-a-record-from-another-table)",  but i could not get this working.

I have a query that selects and updates table `sem_stdexamfinresmark`. The select subquery returns multiple rows of data whose size may not be equal to the table being updated, but the update is now working.

The query looks like :

```
update  sem_stdexamfinresmark sr,
    (select 
         se.currsession,
         str.studentid,
         str.classid,
         str.subjectid,
         str.aggScore*(select gbtp.percentage from gb_termpercentage gbtp where gbtp.termname = se.examtype)/100 as aggPer,
         str.aggGrade
    from 
        sem_stdexamtermresr str,
        sem_exam se 
    where 
        str.examid=se.examid and 
        se.examtype = 'Second Term' and
        se.currsession =1 and classid='8' 
     ) s
     set 
        sr.SecondTermMark = s.aggPer and
        sr.SecondTermGrade = s.aggGrade 
     where
        sr.studentid=s.studentid and 
        sr.subjectid=s.subjectid and 
        s.currsession = s.currsession and
        sr.classid='8';
```

---

EDIT:

```
update  sem_stdexamfinresmark 
 set 
    sr.SecondTermMark = s.aggPer and
    sr.SecondTermGrade = s.aggGrade 
from 
(select 
     se.currsession,
     str.studentid,
     str.classid,
     str.subjectid,
     str.aggScore*(select gbtp.percentage from gb_termpercentage gbtp where gbtp.termname = se.examtype)/100 as aggPer,
     str.aggGrade
from 
    sem_stdexamtermresr str,
    sem_exam se 
where 
    str.examid=se.examid and 
    se.examtype = 'Second Term' and
    se.currsession = 1 and classid='8' 
 ) s
 where
    sr.studentid=s.studentid and 
    sr.subjectid=s.subjectid and 
    s.currsession =1 and
    sr.classid='8';
    select * from sem_exam;
    update sem_exam set currsession =1;
```

Comment: What is your question? What description do you need?

Comment: @Abhay I have a query that inserts into myql database. Now i need to update the recods that i inserted previously by selecting another table but the query is not working properly. I wanted to know how this work.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your query? And assuming there are no syntax errors, when you say that the query is not working properly, mean it is not doing any updates, right? You have mentioned that the subquery is returning results, so the possibility that comes to my mind is that either the WHERE clauses in the UPDATE do not return any matching rows. Can you please confirm if the WHERE finds matching rows?

Comment: Yes it update some record but not all . Though I am updating two columns it update single only and the next is all null. The first one either is not good it's mess. The where clause has all parameters to match to particular row id i.e student I am looking at same query for 2 days I am stuck

Comment: This is what happens when one does silly mistake and moves round and round :( Thanks Abhay and Denis for help I actually had "and" insetad of comma in set statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens when one loses sleep :( I just did a silly mistake here and added "and"

Answer (score 0):

try something that looks more like:

```
update foo
set col = bar.col
from bar
where ...
```

Comment: what do you think about my query any suggestions

Comment: I think you should rewrite your query like I suggested above. When writing an update query, start by writing it as a normal `select * from foo, bar where ...`. Then strip out the field list, and the `foo,` part, and replace them by `update foo set ...`.